# Comparar dos objetos en una función recursiva en javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, recursión, javascript-objeto, comparaciones

Me dan el siguiente problema...
Escribir una función llamada deepEqual que reciba dos argumentos y retorne true si son el mismo valor o si son objetos con las mismas propiedades, en este último caso los valores de las propiedades deben ser comparados con una llamada recursiva de deepEqual.

Usando el operador typeof puedes determinar si ambas variables son objetos, de ser así se debe llamar nuevamente deepEqual para comparar las propiedades de dichos objetos, en caso contrario solo es necesario revisar si ambas variables son estrictamente iguales.

La función Object.keys() es útil para obtener las propiedades de los objetos.

Lo solucioné de esta forma:

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
    if (typeof(a) === "object" && typeof(b)==="object"){
        var aKeys = Object.keys(a).sort();
        var bKeys = Object.keys(b).sort();
        return deepEqual(JSON.stringify(aKeys),JSON.stringify(bKeys))
    }else if (a === b){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
var john = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
};
console.log("Test 1:", deepEqual(1, 1)); // true
console.log("Test 2:", deepEqual(1, "1")); // false
console.log("Test 3:", deepEqual(john, john)); // true
console.log("Test 4:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" })); // true
console.log("Test 5:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John" })); // false
```

Pero he leído que usar JSON.stringify para comparar objetos no es muy buena práctica, conocen alguna forma de darle solución de manera recursiva sin usar JSON.stringify?

Gracias totales de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El uso de `JSON.stringify()` puede ser una mala práctica, dependiendo del uso que le des. En tu caso, no es útil porque necesitas comparar claves y valores, no cadenas.

Aprovechando que ya obtuviste claves de ambos objetos:

1. Compara que la cantidad de claves es la misma
2. Las claves ya están ordenadas, recorre en un ciclo para compararlas
3. Si las claves son iguales, compara los valores

En caso de error en cualquiera de los 3 pasos anteriores, se devuelve falso, porque los objetos no son iguales. Si pasa todas las validaciones, se devuelve verdadero.

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
    if (typeof(a) === "object" && typeof(b)==="object"){
        var aKeys = Object.keys(a).sort();
        var bKeys = Object.keys(b).sort();
        // Primero revisa si hay la misma cantidad de claves
        if(!deepEqual(aKeys.length, bKeys.length)) {
            return false;
        }
        // Recorre las claves para saber que son iguales
        for(let i = 0; i < aKeys.length; i++) {
            if(!deepEqual(aKeys[i], bKeys[i])) {
                return false;
            }
            // Aquí mismo se pueden comparar los valores
            if(!deepEqual(a[aKeys[i]], b[aKeys[i]])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Ya pasaste todas las validaciones, los objetos son iguales
        return true;
    }else if (a === b){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
var john = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
};
console.log("Test 1:", deepEqual(1, 1)); // true
console.log("Test 2:", deepEqual(1, "1")); // false
console.log("Test 3:", deepEqual(john, john)); // true
console.log("Test 4:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" })); // true
console.log("Test 5:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John" })); // false
console.log("Test 6:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John", lastName: "Dow" })); // false
console.log("Test 7:", deepEqual(john, { lastName: "Doe", firstName: "John" })); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Algunos detalles:

- Primero, la función falla si usas algo como:

  ```
  console.log("Test 4A:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John", lastName: "loquesea" }));
  ```

  Porque sólo estás comparando las claves (nombres de las propiedades), pero no los valores.
- Por otro lado, si vas a usar JSON.stringify, te basta con algo así:

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
    //son iguales (primitivas) o son el mismo objeto (misma instancia)
    if (a === b) return true;
    //son objetos
    if (typeof a === typeof b && typeof a == 'object') {
        return deepEqual(JSON.stringify(a),JSON.stringify(b));
    }
    return false;
}
const john = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
};

const johnF = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    t: () =>  console.log("metodo t")
};

console.log("Test 1:", deepEqual(1, 1)); // true
console.log("Test 2:", deepEqual(1, "1")); // false
console.log("Test 3:", deepEqual(john, john)); // true
console.log("Test 4:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" })); // true
console.log("Test 4:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe2" })); // false
console.log("Test 5:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John" })); // false
console.log("Test 6:", deepEqual(john, johnF)); // true MAL
```

**Pero** JSON.stringify:

- ignora las propiedades que son funciones, por lo que no funciona en casos como el Test 6.
- dos objetos equivalentes pero con las claves insertadas en distinto orden se generan distintos strings:

```js
const a= {
  uno: 1,
  dos: 2
};

const b = {
  dos: 2,
  uno: 1
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(a) , JSON.stringify(b), JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b))
```

- Por tanto, puedes comparar propiedad por propiedad de manera recursiva: si es un valor primitivo, lo comparas con `===`, en otro caso vuelves a comprobar sus propiedades

```js
const isObject = x => typeof x == "object" && x != null;
function deepEqual (x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    return true;
  } else if (!isObject(x) || !isObject(y)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (Object.keys(x).length != Object.keys(y).length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (var prop in x) {
    if (!y.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const john = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
};

const johnF = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    t: () =>  console.log("metodo t")
};

console.log("Test 1:", deepEqual(1, 1)); // true
console.log("Test 2:", deepEqual(1, "1")); // false
console.log("Test 3:", deepEqual(john, john)); // true
console.log("Test 4:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" })); // true
console.log("Test 4:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe2" })); // false
console.log("Test 5:", deepEqual(john, { firstName: "John" })); // false
console.log("Test 6:", deepEqual(john, johnF)); // false
```

Comment: Me parece que el único caso de borde que vale la pena mencionar es al comparar arrays, dado que (según el punto de vista) `[1,2,3]` debiera ser `deepEqual` con `[2,3,1]`. Eso ya es un problema de dominio: en un bingo son iguales, en un software de ruteo son distintos e incompatibles.